# Error switching magento 2 version

Tags: magento2, php

On my CLI i have version - 7.4.16 for my PHP
But when I try to load my website in the browser i get this

> Magento supports PHP 7.1.3 or later. Please read Magento System Requirements.

What am I doing wrong ?

http://apex11.com

Answer (score 1):

The PHP version on your CLI and web server *can* be different. Put `phpinfo();die;` directly after the php opening tag to identify the version. If you have recently installed an updated PHP version you *may* just need to reload NGINX (or whatever you are using for your web server).

Identify the version and determine how that is configured on the server then switch it out for the correct version.

Comment: I restarted the apache servere. No success yet.

Comment: But Thank you man, for your try, cause I'm really stuck here

Comment: What version is running on the web server?